# Словосочетание «образование скользкости»

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология, лексическая-сочетаемость

Увидел на днях фразу: "возможно образование скользкости".
Интересует следующее: насколько правильно словосочетание "образование скользкости" (согласно нормам и смыслу). Оно относится к ведомственным документам "Ведомственные строительные нормы. ВСН 20-87".

> Зимнюю скользкость на дорожных покрытиях создают все виды снежно-ледяных отложений, снижающие коэффициент сцепления автомобиля с покрытием. При образовании зимней скользкости ухудшаются условия эксплуатации дороги, уменьшается скорость движения транспортных средств и возрастает количество дорожно-транспортных происшествий.
> Инструкция по борьбе с зимней скользкостью на автомобильных дорогах, утверждена 20 августа 1987 года

Answer (score 1):

Существительное *"скользкость"* звучит канцеляритно, но тем не менее образовано без ошибки, существует в Викисловаре и в Орфографическом словаре.

Итак, *"образование скользкости"* — чудовищный канцелярит, но **это выражение ясно по смыслу и не противоречит правилам**.

Comment: Скользкость — это абстрактное понятие, в отличие от гололёда. Это свойство, нельзя образовать свойство. Поэтому правилам противоречит. Как и, например, "образовать мягкость". Это очевиднее. Но можно поспособствовать мягкости.

Comment: Когда заявляете, что что-то противоречит правилам, приводите искомое правило. Что касается скользкости, то это конкретное свойство совершенно спокойно можно образовать. 'Её голос образовал в его сердце нежность' - чудовищно канцеляритно, но ни буквой, ни смыслом не противоречит правилам русского языка.

Comment: *Поэтому правилам противоречит* — это образно, что так неправильно. Нельзя образовывать/создавать свойства, особенности, какие бы устоявшиеся разговорные фразы вы бы ни привели! Создать можно что-то в чём-то, чтоб это свойство возникло.

Comment: Ну рассматривайте скользкость как акциденцию, то есть несущностное, образовываемое, привносимое свойство, если вам так будет легче.

Comment: *Образуем у него магнитное свойство.* Нормально звучит?

Comment: Звучит канцеляритно, но ошибки нет. Вы гляньте в БТС: первое же значение слова 'образовать' - 'Создать, вызвать появление, возникновение чего-л". И в чём проблема выражения 'Вызовем появление у него магнитного свойства'? Только в том, что это канцелярит.

Comment: Странно, что звучит. Как-то привык к тому, что свойство возникает в результате чего-то, а не образовывается кем-то. В пункте а) нет примера с абстрактным. Ещё есть такая вещь, как сочетаемость слов. *И в чём проблема выражения 'Вызовем появление у него магнитного свойства'?* — в стилистике, "вызовем появление" — так люди не говорят. Всё равно что "вызовем появление Деда Мороза". Хотя стоп, вроде как "вызовем появление" — это плеоназм, "вызовем" уже подразумевает "появление".

Comment: Вы, мне кажется, просто недостаточно хорошо понимаете, что такое канцелярит. Это язык в языке, своего рода секвестр внутри живого тела. В нём возможно то, что моветон в других стилях. Это предельная конкретика, необходимая в юриспруденции, чтобы избавиться от разночтений. "Вызовем Деда Мороза" на канцелярите может значить разное. "Вызовем смерть Деда мороза"? "Вызовем ярость"?.. "Вызовем появление Деда Мороза" же означает, что произошёл именно вызов появления.  "Дети вызвали появление Деда Мороза" -- то есть не просто произвели вызов, а Дед таки на него явился.

Comment: Канцелярит хорошо понимаю, не то что вашу акциденцию. Если "вызвать" — являться причиной, то нет плеоназма. А плеоназм со значением "произвести вызов": нельзя вызывать, чтоб не появился, всегда вызывают, чтоб появился. Но оно и не сочетается, важно понимать, что это разные значения. Нельзя так вставлять слова, никакой юрист так не станет делать, это абсурд. Там рассматривают, что это может значить буквально. Нельзя приплетать ярость, так как о ней речи не было.

Comment: Вызывать, чтоб не появился, можно запросто. "Вечером я вызвал скорую, а она не приехала". Что касается ярости — повторяю: канцелярит — предельно конкретен. Потому что если где-то нет предельной конкретики, то приплести можно всё, и любой адвокат вам это объяснит на примерах.

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. "Что" (у вас) и "чтоб" (для того чтобы) — разные вещи. Любое не приплетается, оно интерпретируется в границах здравого смысла, шарю в юриспруденции. Канцелярит канцеляритом, а нормы стилистики действуют и в деловом стиле, хоть и отличаются. Канцелярит тоже должен звучать, он просто звучит избыточно, но терпимо для большинства. "Вызвать появление" — стилистически неудачно, трудно представить контекст, где бы оно звучало.

Comment: "Национальный подъем последней четверти XIV в. вызвал появление многих исторических произведений" — Дм. Лихачёв. Был такой, если не знаете, филологишка, словами пользоваться не умел, стилистики не знал...

Comment: Не знаю такого. Его порой и заменить не на что, так что проще использовать, чем перестраивать предложение.

Comment: С моей стороны это был, конечно, сарказм. А вы всерьёз не знаете, кто такой Дмитрий Сергеевич Лихачёв? Ну... Я тогда в растерянности. Такого масштаба фигур за всю историю филологии/лингвистики в России не было, пожалуй, и десятка.

Comment: Не интересуюсь филологами. Использую справочники Розенталя и Лопатина... Это всё не настолько сложно для меня, чтоб сидеть в книгах и изучать труды лингвистов. Их же ещё найти нужно. А советского в интернете мало.

Comment: Дело не в сложности, а в понимании. Справочники объясняют как, но не объясняют почему.

Comment: Розенталь объясняет, почему (кстати, здесь запятая нужна). Не напрямую, а своими примерами. Мне всё понятно (даже причины). Да, приходилось порой анализировать, сравнивать. У него примеры объясняют больше, чем сами правила. Примеры очень удачные.

Comment: Зачем здесь запятая?

Comment: Логическое ударение падает на глагол, оно не перетягивается. Такое бывает редко. Здесь связано с повторением слова. У Розенталя сказано, что бывают исключения, но мало он уделил этому.

Comment: У Розенталя нет оговорок в этом правиле. "Не ставится запятая между главной и следующей за ней придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения в случаях: <...> 3) если придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия): Я бы тоже желал знать  почему (Л.Т.); Не знаю  почему,  но я его не понимал (Триф.); Он ушёл и не сказал  куда;  Он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил  когда;  Трудно сказать  почему;  Мать определяла температуру ребёнка губами: приложит их ко лбу и сразу определит  сколько..."

Comment: Ну дальше ж идёт: В условиях контекста возможна постановка запятой или тире и перед одиночным союзным словом: Что же надо делать? Научите, что — усиленное логическое выделение местоимения; Одно время он что-то шептал, не могли понять — что? (А. Т.) — постановка тире подчеркивает значение местоимения и оправдывается вопросительной интонацией.

Comment: Хорошо, оговорка есть, но "возможна" не значит  "нужна".

Comment: Просто в его примере можно без запятой, хотя смысл меняется, а в моём — нет, потому что вся задумка нарушается. Он не мог знать про все возможные ситуации, как и любой другой человек. Важно понимать разницу в произношении, тогда становится понятно, когда можно, а когда нельзя. От контекста всё зависит, как он и сказал.

Answer (score 1):

Скользкость в данном случае не свойство, а **ведомственный термин**, используемый в организациях, занимающихся  зимним содержанием дорог.

Например https://docs.cntd.ru/document/1200032169 Руководство по борьбе с зимней скользкостью на автомобильных дорогах.

**Образование скользкости** – это образование на дорогах **скользкого покрытия** в зимнее время из снега и льда, а **скользкость** – это наличие скользкого покрытия.

Это специальная лексика, которой нет в обычных словарях. Термины позволяют выразить определенные понятия в краткой форме. Они используются только специалистами, поэтому ничего чудовищного в них нет. Собственная терминология используется во многих промышленных и научных отраслях.

Comment: Это никакой не профессиональный термин, а базовая словообразовательная возможность. От любого прилагательного можно образовать существительное с добавлением ‟ость”: красный — красность, быстрый — быстрость, мудрый — мудрость. Не все такие слова считаются нормой, но любое такое слово будет понято носителем.